# How to use Contains in Visual Studio Code Extensions API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, marketplace

I have been using below API to get list of extensions of Visual Studio Code.

I pass extension name and Visual Studio Code as filter parameters to filter out the specific extension which I need. Now I would like to use contains in extension name to filter extensions. How to use contains to filter extensions by extensions name?

Any help is appreciated.

API:

```
POST https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json
accept: application/json;api-version=3.0-preview.1
accept-encoding: gzip

{
  filters: [
    {
      criteria: [
        {
          filterType: 8, 
          value: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code"
        },
        {
          filterType: 10,
          value: "Python"
        }
      ],
      pageNumber: 1,
      pageSize: 100,
      sortBy: 0,
      sortOrder: 0
    }
  ],
  assetTypes: [],
  flags: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here since I had the same question. Unfortunately, The Visual Studio marketplace API is not well documented. However, you can get some information about the inner workings by inspecting the [extensionGalleryService](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/platform/extensionManagement/common/extensionGalleryService.ts#L113-L122) implemented in vscode. In this, you can find a list with the filter types:

```
enum FilterType {
    Tag = 1,
    ExtensionId = 4,
    Category = 5,
    ExtensionName = 7,
    Target = 8,
    Featured = 9,
    SearchText = 10,
    ExcludeWithFlags = 12
}
```

In your case, you will therefore need to use filter type `7` to specify the extension name.

Additionally, you can get more information by sending requests to the API and watching the error messages. A good tool for this is [reqbin](https://reqbin.com/).